# imploding and using database information in arrays

Tags: php

I have a database table that has the IPs of users who visit the website. I'm trying to create an IP ban system for a page. I want the IPs that that are listed as blocked from my database table to be listed in an array of IPs that cannot access this particular page. I keep getting errors and I can't figure out how to get it to work properly. This is what i'm using so far:

PHP:

```
$getBlockedUsers = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT ip FROM blog_comments WHERE blocked='yes'");
$separateIps = implode(", ", mysqli_fetch_array($getBlockedUsers));

if (in_array ($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'], $separateIps)) {
   header("location: http://www.google.com");
   exit();
}
```

- I'm connected to the database correctly

Comment: Why not just search for the row with `ip = $_SERVER[REMOTE_ADDR]`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$getBlockedUsers = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT true FROM blog_comments WHERE blocked='yes' AND ip='" . $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] . "' LIMIT 1");

if ($getBlockedUsers->num_rows > 0) {
   header("location: http://www.google.com");
   exit();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `implode` function,

```
$separateIps = mysqli_fetch_all($getBlockedUsers, MYSQL_NUM);
```

`in_array` expects parameter 2 to be an array. When using `implode` you will get a string instead of an array.

Comment: That's just one row of the table, not all the IPs.

Comment: @Barmar I am pretty sure he meant `mysqli_fetch_all`.

Comment: I believe Barmar is right. I'll need to test this. It has removed the errors. But I'm not sure if this will work for all IPs.

Comment: @PLB That won't work either, because it returns a multidimensional array.